help with understanding D-modules and crystals
The setup is as follows: if $A$ is a $k-$algebra and $I$ is the kernel of the multiplication map $A\otimes_k A\to A$ I see that there is an isomorphism $\Omega_{A/k}\to I/I^2$ given by $da\to a\otimes 1- 1\otimes a$. we can form a ring $A\oplus \Omega_A$ which is the first truncation of $Sym^\bullet\Omega_A$. We get an isomorphism $A\oplus \Omega_A\to (A\otimes A)/I^2$ which identifies $A\oplus \Omega_A$ with the first order neighbourhood of the diagonal. We have two maps $Spec(A\oplus \Omega)\to Spec(A)$, one coming from $\pi_1:a\mapsto a$ and another one from $\pi_2:a\mapsto a+da$. These correspond to the two projection $Spec(A)\times Spec(A)\to Spec A$. Let $M$ be an $A-$module.
Now I explain my questions:
There is a claim saying that giving an isomorphism $\pi_1^*M\to \pi_2^*M$ is equivalent to giving a connection $\nabla:M\to \Omega_{A/k}\otimes M$.
Here is my attempt to see this: first note that this is the same as giving a map
$M\to \pi_{1,*}\pi_2^* M$
by a formula
$$
\phi: m\to m\otimes 1+\nabla(m),
 $$
where $\nabla(m)$ is an expression of a form $\sum m_i\otimes da_i\in M\otimes (A\oplus \Omega_A)$. One checks that $\nabla$ is a connection. Namely, for any $a\in A$ and $m\in M$ we get
\begin{align*}
   & am\otimes 1 +\nabla(am)=\phi(a\cdot m)=\pi_1(a)\phi(m)=(a+da)\cdot (m\otimes 1+\nabla(m))=\\ (m\otimes a) &+m\otimes da+a\otimes \nabla(m) +1\otimes (da\cdot \nabla(m))= m\otimes a +m\otimes da+a\otimes \nabla(m).
\end{align*}
Comparing parts "belonging to $M\otimes \Omega_A\subset M\otimes (A\oplus \Omega_A)$" on the left and right we get
$$
\nabla(am)=\nabla(m)\otimes a+m\otimes da.
$$
MY QUESTIONS

I don't have a clean way of seeing that the morphism $\phi$ in the proof has a nice form $$m\otimes 1+\nabla(m)$$ where $\nabla(m)$ involves only summands of the form $n\otimes da$. This should follow from the facts that both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ have a common section $A\oplus \Omega_A\to A$ (given by quotienting by $\Omega$) and that $\pi_1^*M\to \pi_2^*M$ is an isomorphism. My attempt is by explicit description of tensor products and I don't show it here, I am looking for more "functorial" point of view.

Also, I am not satisfied with geometric picture here and I would love to hear a comment on that as well. Geometrically, $Spec(A\oplus \Omega)\to Spec(A)$ induced by $a\to a$ realizes $Spec(A\oplus \Omega)$ as a "bundle of infinitesimal tanget vectors" over $Spec(A)$. The other projection (the one corresponding to the map of rings $a\to (a+da)$) projects set theoretically a pair $(x,v)$ consisting of a point $x$ and a "very short" tanget vector $v$ to $"x+v"$. Thus giving an isomoprhism between the two pullbacks of a module $M$ corresponds to giving an action of tangent vectors on $M$. Could someone elaborate on that?

Is the following reasonable:
A map $f:Y\to Sym^\bullet \Omega_A$ represents data of a map towards $Spec(A)$ together with a section of $f^*T(Spec(A))$ (here $T$ stands for tangent space). Note that $A\oplus \Omega_A$ can be viewed as degree $0$ and $1$ parts of $Sym^\bullet \Omega_A$. Therefore $\Omega_A$ represents sections of tangent bundle which are infinitesimally close to the zero section (so close such that their "squares" are $0$).

The tool that helps me understand the above is an isomorphism $(A\otimes A)/I^2= A\oplus \Omega$.  Can I perform a similar reasoning for higher neighbourhoods of the diagonal? My worry is for example that $\Omega^\bullet$ is not commutative. In other words I would like to see that $I/I^k$ corresponds to the dual differential operators of degree smaller than $k$ (do I have to assume $k\to A$ is smooth for that?).


